# Bokeh CDSView with line glyphs

Tags: bokeh

I'm using Bokeh line glyphs with `nan` values to create an image with many line segments.

I would like to selectively turn some of these glyphs off.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

My first attempt is to have a `visible` column, and use a [CDSView](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#filtering-data-with-cdsview) to turn each line segment on or off.  However this has no effect, I suspect because bokeh identifies all of these line segments as a single glyph.  Is there a way to use CDSView to turn off various parts of a `line` glyph?  Is there another glyph that I should be looking at instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a `multi_line` glyph, which lets you plot a lot of individual line segments declared as separate arrays. Once you've done that you could control the visibility of each line segment by declaring a separate alpha column. Here is a minimal example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

p = figure()
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'xs': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
    'ys': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],
    'alpha': [0, 1]
})
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', line_alpha='alpha', source=source)
show(p)
```

Comment: I'll need to stick with CDSView so that my axes align with only the visible data.  Pushing me towards the `multi_line` glyph was very helpful.  Thanks!